# Is using lex/yacc (or flex/bison) an overkill for configuration file parsing?

Tags: parsing, configuration, bison, flex-lexer

For the last couple of weeks I kept reading and playing with flex/bison, the main goal is to parse structured configuration file with nested groups and lists.

flex/bison seems very powerful but too complicated.

I surveyed few open source project and the only example I found for configuration parsing using Bison was ntpd, other projects build their own parser and lexer.

Is it really the right tool for the job? or is it better to build a recursive descent parser by hand (may be with flex as a lexer)?!

Comment: If you think you need it it's probably a sign that you have over-designed your file format. Configuration files aren't programs and shouldn't need compiler technology to process them. They should be simple to write, by non-programmers, and therefore simple to process.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it's too complicated. Besides, handwritten parsers are poorly maintainable, compared to autogenerated parsers.

The biggest problem with GNU Bison and Flex is that there is no good tutorial for C++. There are plenty of badly written C examples with global variables, which doesn't help *Bison/Flex* reputation. Your percepsion may change when you have a working example.

Here is a working **C++** solution using **Bison 3** and **Flex**. Encapsulate it in your own namespace and voila - you can stuff your project with gazilion parsers for everything.

https://github.com/ezaquarii/bison-flex-cpp-example

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely appropriate.   If you are versed in bison you can throw it together way quicker than you could write an RDP or some kind of ad-hoc parser.   Might take a little longer if it's your first go at it - but it might also be a good way to learn.

It will also help you design your grammar - if you accidentally make it ambiguous, you'll get a R/R conflict right away, rather than getting way down to a depp dark place in your RDP and finding you have no way out...

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of home-brew configuration file syntaxes that have been developed using primitive ad-hoc approaches, such as splitting a line into a name and value based on simple tokenizing. Such approaches [tend to have limitations](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/comparison-with-other-technologies.html#toc31), and Java properties files come to mind as [a particularly bad configuration format](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/comparison-with-other-technologies.html#toc32).

When you have made the decision to define a lexical and BNF specification for your configuration syntax, you are already ahead of the game. Whether you then choose to implement that specification via hand-written code or via tools such as flex & bison is just a relatively unimportant implementation detail.

When I designed and implemented [Config4*](http://www.config4star.org/), I choose the hand-written code approach, for [reasons I discuss in one of the Config4* manuals](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-maintenance-guide/parsers-and-lexical-analysers.html#htoc36). However, I agree with the advice from BadZen: if you are already comfortable using flex and bison, then using them will probably save time compared to using a hand-written lexer and recursive-descent parser.